# Computational models where halting problem is solvable

Tags: halting-problem

Are there computational models that can be considered *useful* for solving common programming problems, where it can be proven that computation will terminate for all possible inputs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)

Comment: You can consider any Turing-complete language together with a proof that the program halts. Most useful programs that halt can be proven to halt.